# Complex Differentiability at a Point Equivalent to Having an Affine Part

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, linear-approximation

I’m trying to prove that a function $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow\mathbb C$ continuous at some point $a$ has affine part $Az+B\overline z+C$ if and only if it is differentiable at $a$. Note: The affine part of $f$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac{|f(z)-(Az+B\overline z+C)|}{|z-a|}=0$, and I take $\lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}=w$ to be the definition of $f’(a)$ provided $w$ exists. I have the forward direction of the proof, but I’m stuck trying to show the converse; namely, differentiability at $a$ gives rise to the affine part. Since we assume differentiability at $a$, we have continuity at $a$. Then, my idea is to consider the linear approximation $f’(a)(z-a)+f(a)$ and manipulate it to the form $Az+B\overline z +C$, but I’m stuck doing so. Can anyone get me on the right track?

In my mind, the affine part of the function is the best linear approximation, so it is similar to the line tangent to the graph of a real-valued function at a point. This is why I am attempting to use the linear approximation written above.

Comment: The forward direction is not true--to get differentiability, you more strongly need an affine part with $B=0$.

Comment: You are confusing real differentiability (i.e. as a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, which you are asked to show equivalent to the existence of an affine part $Az+B\bar z+C$) with complex differentiability (defined by any of the two other conditions you wrote), and which is obviously (strictly) stronger. I am very doubtful you succeeded in proving the "forward direction", and surprised you are stuck in proving the converse.

Comment: To expand upon the earlier comments, any function $f$ on $\Bbb C$ can be considered instead as a function on $\Bbb R^2$, per $z = x + iy$. But note that $x = \frac{z + \bar z}2, y = \frac{z - \bar z}2$, which allows you to think of $f$ as a 2-variable function of $z, \bar z$. If you develop this idea, it turns out that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are exactly that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$. That is, if $f$ is differentiable, then by this process, $f$ turns out to still be a function of $z$ alone, not $\bar z$. $Az + B\bar z + C$ is a function of $\bar z$ except when $B = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I reasoned B = 0 since I know the Wirtinger derivatives (or Cauchy-Riemann equations) provide independence of $\overline z$ for a differentiable function. I didn't write that in my original post, and I think I have the converse of the statement after having some more thought.